# Eclipse not recognizing imports from JavaFX JDK 8

Tags: eclipse, javafx, import

I have installed JDK 8 which includes JavaFX and configured it in the project build path. However, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>Shift</kbd> **+** <kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports from JavaFX, Eclipse cannot find those classes.

I have verified that `jfxrt.jar` is in the correct folder and configured in the build path. I can even navigate through that JAR under the JRE System Library folder. I can also import classes manually, e.g. by writing

```
import javafx.application.Application;
```

for the `Application` class. However, when I open the file again, Eclipse complains again that `Application` cannot be resolved to a type, even though the *import* statement is still there. I have also tried deleting the project and re-importing it, as suggested in another question here on StackOverflow – to no avail.
Following some screenshots of relevant settings.
[image: Java build path]
[image: Java compiler settings]
[image: Installed JREs]
[image: Problems page 1]
[image: Problems page 2]
[image: Java FX classes]
[image: Import statements]
[image: About Eclipse IDE]

Comment: Make sure you have a Java 8 JDK configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: I do have that.

Comment: Then please show your project settings and what you have in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_. Show also what problems are shown in the _Problems_ view (you can copy and paste them as text into your question).

Comment: I think we're not supposed to paste screenshots here - is that right? So I'm not exactly sure how to provide this information. In project properties, compiler compliance level is set to 1.8. In _Java -> Installed JREs_ there is a jdk1.8.0_301, an openJDK17.0.1 and a jre1.8.0_301 with the jdk1.8.0_301 selected. In the problems view I get a million errors which are all of the type "X cannot be resolved to a type". Please let me know if there's a better way to provide information!

Comment: You can insert screenshots here, but with your low reputation rating as a link only. Please sort or filter the problems to check whether there are other problems than _"X cannot be resolved to a type"_.

Comment: I made a zip file with the requested screenshots. Here is a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/afsx5zux0mwd41k/JavaFX%20issue.zip?dl=0

Comment: Maybe you have not an Oracle Java 8 JDK, but an OpenJDK where JavaFX is missing, see https://adoptium.net/docs/migration/#_openjfx Does your Java 8 installation contain the file `jfxrt.jar`?

Comment: @howlger It's an Oracle Java 8 JDK and includes jfxrt.jar.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that on your first screenshot. Are those JavaFX classes displayed in your project below the `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]` node?

Comment: @howlger Yes. I added another screenshot where you can see that e.g. the `WebEngine` class is there, but Eclipse still complains that it can't be resolved to a type.

Comment: Strange. Are no errors displayed on the imports? Do the corresponding imports exist (I cannot see it as line 3..16 is folded)?

Comment: @howlger No errors on the imports (see above). The imports are there. I added the import for `WebEngine` manually, which makes the error disappear until I re-open the file. Another strange behaviour is that the import works for some classes like `Application` but not for others. Furthermore, Eclipse seems in some way to recognize even the problematic classes - e.g. when i place the cursor on `WebEngine` and press `F3`, Eclipse opens a view of the source code of that class.

Comment: According to your first screenshot you are using an outdated Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger Not sure what you mean by that. It was version 2022-06, so relatively new. I updated it to the current version (see screenshot), but that didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: I "solved" the problem now by doing a fresh installation of eclipse and reconstructing the project from just the source code. Now everything works fine again. Of course, that doesn't explain why it couldn't be made to work with the version I had.